# How to create tuples inside list of tuples - Python

Tags: python, list, tuples

My aim is to create a tuple inside another tuple, for example:
`(398905, 6340963, 2019)` should become `((398905, 6340963), 2019)`

I created a Pandas DataFrame which I converted into a list of tuples:

```
#create dataframe with 3 rows, 4 columns
data = {'X_coords':[398905, 492561, 496561], 'Y_coords':[6340963, 6526362, 6527362], 'YEAR': [2019, 2020, 2020], 'ID':[1,2,3]}
#to pandas dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

#creating a list of tuples from dataframe entries
df_tuple = [tuple(x) for x in df.values.tolist()]
#examine
print(df_tuple)

#prints:
[(398905, 6340963, 2019, 1), (492561, 6526362, 2020, 2), (496561, 6527362, 2020, 3)]
```

Considering my aim, the result should become:
`[((398905, 6340963), 2019, 1), ((492561, 6526362), 2020, 2), ((496561, 6527362), 2020, 3)]`

What is a convenient way of achieving this?

Comment: `[((x[0], x[1]), x[2], x[3]) for x in df.values]`?

Comment: What is the expected input? Is it the dictionary `data`, or is it a `DataFrame`. If the former, then you probably don't even need to use a data frame to start with, considering that you're only using the `df.values.tolist()` value, which you can get directly with `data.values()`, or by iterating on `data` directly (will loop through the values, and ignores the keys)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the easiest way is to do:

```py
df_tuple = [((i[:2]),*i[2:]) for i in df.values.tolist()]
```

Basically saying you take the first items and put them in a tuple, then unpack the remaining items in the "larger" tuple.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to group the first to elements of each tuple of the list, you could use a comprehension:

```
[((a, b),*c) for a, b, *c in df_tuples]
```

it gives as expected:

```
[((398905, 6340963), 2019, 1), ((492561, 6526362), 2020, 2), ((496561, 6527362), 2020, 3)]
```

Comment: ".values" should be added, I think (i.e. [((a, b),*c) for a, b, *c in df_tuples.values]

Comment: In OP's question, `df_tuples` is a list of tuples. The dataframe is named `df`.

Answer (score 0):

You could `apply` the required format and then convert `tolist` - i.e.

```py
df.apply(lambda row: ((row['X_coords'], row['Y_coords']), row['YEAR'], row['ID']), axis=1).tolist()
```

**Output**

```
[((398905, 6340963), 2019, 1),
 ((492561, 6526362), 2020, 2),
 ((496561, 6527362), 2020, 3)]
```

Answer (score 0):

It is a one line solution which works directly with your data. Standard library is more than powerful for easy tasks

```
result = [((x, y), t, i) for x, y, t, i in zip(*[v for _, v in data.items()])]
```